# How to limit rate of out going http calls in scaled microservice?

Tags: spring, http, microservices, rate-limiting

I have a scenario in which my microservice is scaled to 3 instances. Each service makes http calls to third party service. However, the third party service has a rate limit i.e. it cannot accept more than 1000 requests per second. Now that I have 3 instances of same service running its hard to keep track of count. Any solutions that could help me implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Circuit Breaker](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) pattern and tools like [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) in such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is based on assumption that each service is independent and don't interact with each others and **can possibly scaled up or down**.

Use **Redis data cache service**, introduce a variable there. Each service will be able to refer that variable and will update when ever they make a API call, write **some conditions** so no service is allow to make calls if its reach to 1000 for that specific second .

Hence they will not be able to make more than 1000 call per seconds.